# Bound for sum with geometric progression

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, approximation

Let $n_i$, $i=1,\ldots,m+1$ be nonnegative natural numbers, sum of which $\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}n_i=N$.

I woul like to find an upper bound for the following$$
\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}\frac{\sqrt n_i}{2^{i-1}}$$

Comment: How about $\sum_{i=1}^{m+1} \frac{\sqrt{N}}{2^{i-1}}$?

Comment: @Aryabhata: would it be true? In this case, using geometric progression, we get bound $\frac{\sqrt N}{2^{m+1}}$. Now comparig with  result in the answer...

Comment: @David: I think it is: $\sqrt{n_i} \le \sqrt{N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $x=(\sqrt{n_1},...,\sqrt{n_{m+1}})$, $y=(1,\frac{1}{2},...,\frac{1}{2^m})$, the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality ($<x,y> \leq ||x|| ||y||$) gives
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}\frac{\sqrt n_i}{2^{i-1}} \leq \sqrt{N} \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4^{m+1}}}$$